# reading configuration file (mytest.exe.config)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a project with multiple configuration files, I need to be able to read a specific configuration file (`MyTest.exe.config`).

The file looks like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="1.1.1.1"/>   
    <add key="Setting2" value="34567"/>   
    <add key="Setting3" value="blue"/>    
    <add key="Setting4" value="plastic"/>  
</appSettings>
```

Code to read it looks like this:

```
try
{
    ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "MyTest.exe.config";
    Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var appSettings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;

    if (appSettings.Count == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AppSettings is empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var key in appSettings.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, appSettings[key].ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error reading app settings");
}
```

But I only get the keys and no values

Output:

```
Key: Setting1 Value: System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement
Key: Setting2 Value: System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement
Key: Setting3 Value: System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement
Key: Setting4 Value: System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement
```

I also tried to get one value at a time:

```
try
{
    String key = "Setting1";

    ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "MyTest.exe.config";

    Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    var appSettings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;
   
    string result = appSettings[key].ToString();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
catch (ConfigurationErrorsException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error reading app settings");
}
```

But same thing - the output is:

```
System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: appSettings[key].Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you must use property value:

```
foreach (var key in appSettings.AllKeys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, appSettings[key].Value);
}
```

and later, to obtain value you must use:

```
string result = appSettings[key].Value;
```

Try and good luck

Comment: perfect!-This answers works great...